# life is feudal - freezing/crashing every 3 - 5 minutes, how to prevent it from that?

Tags: life-is-feudal

Life is feudal - freezing/crashing every 3 - 5 minutes, how to prevent it from that?

I tried to change many in-game settings, but it only helps to delay it a bit more further.

Prior I had settings almost everything at lowest or mediocre details, there are too many settings - to list a bit of them when all disabled - a depth of field, vsync, light rays, but I was running it at 4k. And I was selectively disabling and testing one after one. I think it could have been due to graphics card 2070 RTX.

Comment: Hello ! Could you improve the question by giving us more info about your settings and setup ?

Comment: Settings actually don't really play a role, as  I had disabled almost any possible option, just running it at 4K but anyway after doing that change in afterburner I can have configured everything at maximum, at it is still doing well. I will adjust it a bit though.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using a utility called afterburner, where it is enough to decrease GPU memory clock under -277 and the game does not crash anymore a single time.
A similar solution used to work also for other games like Kingdome Come, and in Kingdome Come forum it was mentioned it helped also to other games like Elite Dangerous. (
https://forum.kingdomcomerpg.com/t/weird-black-screen-problem/54283/53 
)

https://www.msi.com/page/afterburner